# Using LMDWebHTTPGet downloads the file to the Temporary Internet Files directory only

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

Using LMDWebHTTPGet1 from LMD Innovative downloads the file to the Temporary Internet Files directory only I would like to get it into a directory of my choice

Answer (score 0):

TLMDWebHTTPGet uses the same underlying infrastructure that for instance Internet Explorer and Google Chrome use (adding benefits of for instance sharing proxy settings).

I don't think you can redirect that layer to your own download folder.

So do the same as Internet Explorer does:

1. download it to the "Temporary Internet Files" directory,
2. copy it to the final location,
3. remove the temporary file.

--jeroen